# Getting error while calling action using console based action in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am able to call the action using console by defining the console based path in module.config.php but unable to call http request based action inside the console based action.

when i call the following request:

```
$response = $this->_forward()->dispatch("LoL\Controller\V1\Rest\Farm", array(
                    'action' => 'post',                    
                    'user' => '',
                    'payload' => 'ddd'
            ));
```

getting following error

```
Call to undefined method Zend\Console\Response::getStatusCode() in /var/www/html/webapp/datasilo/module/LoL/src/LoL/Mvc/View/Http/ExceptionStrategy.php on line 81
```

Please anybody let me know how to call http based action inside the console based action.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that your controller extends the `AbstractConsoleController` instead of `AbstractActionController`

In the `AbstractConsoleController` there is no Controller plugin `forward()`.

Comment: It is solved now, there was some authentication issue due to which it wasn't working. thanks for reply.